# How to fix drawer application with latest react-native

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error in starting template of drawer application

Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing. Falling back to JS-based animation. To resolve this, add `RCTAnimation` module to this app, or remove `useNativeDriver`. Make sure to run `pod install` first. Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md

```html
{
  "name": "awesomeproject-type",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.66.13",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "~45.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Hello! Did you import the `react-native-gesture-handler` at the top of your entry file? Another question, did you follow all steps of the [installation guide for Reanimated 2](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/)?

Comment: yes, i did both but still having same issue

Comment: Is it the issue in iOS if so you might need to run pod install by going into iOS folder as per your error.

Comment: this is on chrome web